# Kubernetes Pod Scheduling failed with 1 node(s) did not match pod affinity/anti-affinity

Tags: kubernetes

We have got a Kubernetes cluster up and running (with 1 master and 1 slave).

Recently we added a new worker node (temp-worker) which was successful and all were on Cent OS 8

**Node Details**

```
NAME            STATUS   ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
master-node     Ready    control-plane,master   34d     v1.20.2
temp-worker     Ready    <none>                 5h48m   v1.20.2
worker-node-2   Ready    worker                 34d     v1.20.0
```

I tried with the following pod specification (with 2 replicas), however pod remained in state **Pending**

**Pod Spec**

```
   podAffinity:
     requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
     - labelSelector:
         matchExpressions:
         - key: app                      #security
           operator: DoesNotExist
       topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    podAntiAffinity:
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: app                      #security
              operator: In
              values:
              - hello-app
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

**Pod logs**

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age    From               Message
  ----     ------            ----   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m50s  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity rules, 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 2 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
  Warning  FailedScheduling  3m50s  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity rules, 1 node(s) didn't match pod affinity/anti-affinity, 2 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

I tried by changing the operator values (eg In, NotIn etc) in pod specification but nothing changed

I would like to understand why it reports error for the newly added worker-node.  What did I do wrong ?

Comment: The "volume node affinity conflict" message suggests there's some sort of storage-related issue; does the Pod spec mount a PersistentVolumeClaim that can't be remounted on another node?

Answer (score 0):

From this kubernetes [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#rolling-back-a-deployment) “The Deployment controller stops the bad rollout automatically, and stops scaling up the new ReplicaSet. This depends on the rollingUpdate parameters (maxUnavailable specifically) that you have specified. Kubernetes by default sets the value to 25%.”

Means that it prevents Kubernetes from evicting one pod out of three. You are attempting a deployment update.

Try adding the Max unavailable to deployment .

```
strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        rollingUpdate:
          maxUnavailable: 1
```

As per this [doc](https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/scheduling/podaffinity.md) check whether all conditions are satisfied in your pod affinity.

Try specifying the label values  in the podAffinity, Maybe there are no matching nodes available in the that label values follow this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#an-example-of-a-pod-that-uses-pod-affinity) for more information.